# What are the advantages of angle embedding over amplitude embedding?

Tags: machine-learning

With $n$ qubits, $2^n$ features can be encoded with amplitude embedding, while only $n$ with angle embedding. So, is there any reason to use angle embedding?

Comment: what's your definition/understanding of amplitude and angle encoding?

Comment: @glS see https://docs.pennylane.ai/en/stable/code/api/pennylane.AmplitudeEmbedding.html and https://docs.pennylane.ai/en/stable/code/api/pennylane.AngleEmbedding.html, for example

Answer (score 2):

One of the main advantage of angle embedding is that it can be performed in a constant time with parralelism : each qubit will go through a rotation gate in parralel.

Using only one gate to encode each qubit reduces the noises which are important in today's NISQ computers.